# How to compare sum the values of radio buttons >=3

Tags: jquery

Help please. I have the sum value with different names in one div and need to do
" if sum of all values (0+1+6 or 1+1+2  etc) >= 3 do * 3000, else do * 4000 (instead of * 3000) "
I tried adding this code but it doesn t work correctly. Can t understand why. I m not professional sorry
Here s https://codepen.io/evg33/pen/OJvVJMe my code

```
    jQuery(function ($) { 
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
  $(this).change(calculate);
});

function calculate() {
  var result = 0;
  $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
      
      const val = Number($(this).val());
      result += val * (val >= 3 ? 3000 : 4000);

  });
  
  $("#result").html(result);
}

    });
```

```
<div><label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" 
       name="one" value="0">
    </label>
 
<label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" 
       name="one" value="1">
    </label>
 
<label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" 
       name="two" value="1">
    </label>
 
<label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" 
       name="two" value="6">
    </label>
 
<label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" 
       name="three" value="2">
    </label>
 
<label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" 
       name="three" value="7">
    </label>
</div>
<span id="result">- </span>
```

This code works good (so I guess the problem is not in html). All sums are correct

```
    jQuery(function ($) { 
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
  $(this).change(calculate);
});

function calculate() {
  var result = 0;
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
      result += Number($(this).val()) * 3000;
  });
  
  $("#result").html(result);
}

    });
```

Comment: Where you do `reuslt+=Number(val)*3000`, remove the *3000 then after the .each check the result and *3000 or *4000 at that point.   I'm not sure what the problem is; you already have the code/techniques, just need to move where you make the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the multiplication to the total value you need to first calculate the total from the selected radio inputs. Then you can work out the factor to be applied.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let calcTotal = () => {
    let total = $radio.filter(':checked').get().reduce((t, el) => t + +el.value, 0);
    let factor = total >= 3 ? 3000 : 4000;
    return total * factor;
  }

  let $total = $('#result');
  let $radio = $(':radio').on('change', () => {
    $total.text(calcTotal());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="one" value="0"> 0
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="one" value="1"> 1
  </label><br />

  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="1"> 1
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="two" value="6"> 6
  </label><br />

  <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="three" value="2"> 2
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="three" value="7"> 7
  </label>
</div>
<span id="result">- </span>
```